# Text too close to edge of screen

Tags: html, css

How can I fix so that the text on my webpage is not too close to the left edge of the window? Makes it weird to read as it is aligned to the left far too much.

```
<h1 class="title text-center">Privacy Policy</h1>

<b>Personal identification information</b><br><br>

We may collect personal identification information from Users in a variety of ways, including, but not limited to, when Users visit our site, register on the site, place an order, subscribe to the newsletter, fill out a form, and in connection with other activities, services, features or resources we make available on our Site. Users may be asked for, as appropriate, name, email address, mailing address, phone number, credit card information. Users may, however, visit our Site anonymously. We will collect personal identification information from Users only if they voluntarily submit such information to us. Users can always refuse to supply personally identification information, except that it may prevent them from engaging in certain Site related activities.<br><br>

<b>Non-personal identification information</b><br><br>

We may collect non-personal identification information about Users whenever they interact with our Site. Non-personal identification information may include the browser name, the type of computer and technical information about Users means of connection to our Site, such as the operating system and the Internet service providers utilized and other similar information.<br><br>

<b>Web browser cookies</b><br><br>
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/margin

Comment: Add padding to containing element or reduce the width.

Comment: How about posting your CSS too?

Answer (score 2):

I find css property margin of use here also.

```
 margin: 25px;
```

also note:

```
 margin-top: 25px;
 margin-bottom: 25px;
 margin-left: 25px;
 margin-right: 25px;
```

This is also a good time to start examining media queries, so you can change the margins depending on the device (aka screen width)

> Check out breakpoints. You could design your site for 300px width and then use media queries to define property changes as screen size increases, or you could do the reverse and design it for desktop computers 1400px+ and scale down at breakpoints.

```
body {
  margin: 25px;
  display: flex;
}

@media (max-width: 1400px) {
  body {
    margin: 10px;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 1024px) {
  body {
    margin: 0px;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use css and padding

Wrap your content in a container

```
<div class="container"> ... </div>
```

and use padding:

```
.container {
   padding: 15px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to above use padding-left to control only the left padding.

```
P {
    padding-left:10px;
 }
```